# Entry filter for list of directories

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter a list composed of multiple dictionaries for useless entries and non-ideal fields. An entry is useless if `Mem['visibility'] == "redacted"` and then should be removed from the list. An entry is non-ideal when any of the fields are empty, and these should be filled with a 0 instead or if `Mem['~whatever~']` is a list in which case the list should be transformed into a single string with all the objects in that list.

```
class Filter:
    @staticmethod
    def members(memberlist):
        for Mem in memberlist[:]:
            for Item in Mem:
                if not Mem[Item]:
                    Mem[Item] = 0
                if (type(Mem[Item]) is list):
                    Mem[Item] = ', '.join(Mem[Item])
            if(Mem['visibility'] == "redacted"):
                print(Mem)
                memberlist.remove(Mem)
        return(memberlist)
```

Sample `memberlist`:

```
[{'roles': [], 'rank': 'No SCB account', 'type': 'main', 'stars': 2, 'visibility': 'visible', 'sid': 'imperium', 'handle': 'freakyeagle'}, {'roles': [], 'rank': 'Fleet Member', 'type': 'main', 'stars': 1, 'visibility': 'visible', 'sid': 'imperium', 'handle': 'cadimus'}, {'roles': [], 'rank': 'Fleet Member', 'type': 'main', 'stars': 1, 'visibility': 'visible', 'sid': 'imperium', 'handle': 'belleal'}]
```

How can I make this as simple/efficient as possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You could use a list and generator comprehension instead of `memberlist[:]`.
- You should use `snake_case` instead of `CamelCase` for variables.
- You should use `isinstance` rather than `type() is`.
  This is as it works on objects that extend `list`. E.g. `class MyCustomList(list): pass`.
- You should remove the `print`.
  They are quite slow, and is probably left over from debugging.

If I were to do the above I would use:

```
def members(member_list):
    def handle_nonideal(item):
        if not item:
            return 0
        if isinstance(item, list):
            return ', '.join(item)
        return item

    return [
        {
            key: handle_nonideal(item)
            for key, item in member.items()
        }
        for member in member_list
        if member['visibility'] != 'redacted'
    ]
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at `member for member_list` is that Python3 compliant?

Comment: @Arengorn I made a typo, but unfixed it somehow... It's fixed now.